# mySQL - Insert every possible combination of values into two columns

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a set of values that I am looking to `INSERT` into a **pair** of columns via PHP using a mysql_query, I am having trouble writing the query. I am looking to achieve something similar to the results below, avoiding repetition:

```
Column 1  || Column 2

John      || John
John      || Richard
John      || Kim
Richard   || Richard
Richard   || John
Richard   || Kim
Kim       || Kim
Kim       || John
Kim       || Richard
```

**NOTE:** The example above is just an example of how I'd want the columns to look once the data is inserted. I'd be declaring 'John, Richard and Kim' as `VALUES` in the `INSERT` query, I'm just uncertain on how to achieve this.

I have not yet come anywhere close to success, however I will make an update (with my query) if I get any closer to being successful.

Thanks in advance guys, Rich.

Comment: You should clarify what you are using; mysql or sql server.

Comment: You should also show, what query you have tried so far

Comment: So - are you asking about PHP - how to identify the unique pairs - or about SQL - how to insert them?  Show us the PHP that you have now, and / or refine your question a bit.

Comment: I've refined the question a little.

Answer (score 2):

You need a cross join

```
select a.value as Column1, b.value as Column2
from yourTable a 
cross join YourTable b
```

If you were inserting this into another table you would do something like this:-

```
insert into NewTable (col1, col2)
select a.value as Column1, b.value as Column2
from yourTable a 
cross join YourTable b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
 a.a + CAST( b AS VARCHAR(2)) AS c
INTO Tablec
FROM tablea a
CROSS JOIN tableb AS b;

SELECT 
 CAST( b.b AS VARCHAR(2)) + a AS d
INTO Tabled
FROM tableb b
CROSS JOIN tablea AS a
;



SELECT c FROM tablec Union SELECT d FROM tabled
```

Make use of the code in below sql fiddle [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a84e5/17)